# Verify a signed Firebase user from Symfony backend

Tags: php, symfony, firebase, firebase-authentication, symfony-3.4

I have a firebase project and I use a simple web page to login to firebase with username and password just like below...

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword
 ('test.account@gmail.com', 'password').
 catch(function (error) {

 });
```

And I got the response like below...

```
 {
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "iWFUfdgdsdfsC2",
    "email": "test.account@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "whfGUWiyDE74HsnwN5ZkJn7gX",
    "registered": true,
    "refreshToken": "SZaG1tmzkgn5EImQ_nRj8",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

I followed "kreait/firebase-bundle". But didn't get any idea.

My question is is there any way to verify the signed user from symfony backend ?

Someone please help me...